Energetically, how can evaporation water rise to a specific height/layer in the air then form "stable" (as in molecules grouped together) clouds?

When water evaporates due to sunlight, it rises up in the sky. This requires energy. What effect provides this energy? If all gas molecules were identical, there would be no reason for any to rise. Any motion would be random, so a rising molecule would equalize a falling one. But for water in air, what causes molecules of a specific type, all to rise, given the density differences mean a potential energy difference? This is different than the energy of vaporization. When water condenses in clouds to rain droplets, heat will be released, which was the energy of vaporization. Then the droplets fall, which releases the energy that was stored while lifting the molecules. The explanations that there is a temperature difference that causes updraft doesn't seem plausible, since the process is so slow, there is hardly any temperature difference between the air, the water vapor, and the body of water (assume that it is at the same temperature as the air, which isn't a far-fetched initial setup; I don't think that would prohibit the process of evaporation and rise of water vapor).
Why can water disperse non-homogeneously in air, then mix homogeniously, then separate non-homogeneously again in clouds, while other gases all mix evenly, despite density differences?

I've read several questions & answers on convection & rainfall, but none seem to answer the questions. An evoparation process, even due to sunlight, is a relatively slow enough process, that the evaporating water, especially due to turbulence, will fully mix with the air, hence will have the same average temperature as the air. So why/how does it continue to rise, even though technically it is a gas here just like other elements of air, even though despite all the temperature differences around the earth, oxygen, nitrogen, co2, and trace gases usually don't separate under the influence of temperature differences. So why can water? Each gas element has a difference in density, so why can water separate and rise and then group together to form clouds despite being previously fully mixed with air, but not the other components of air? Why aren't there ever oxygen/nitrogen/noble clouds & rain? The rising process of water molecules requires energy, that will be given back later when the water falls to the ground (not when it condenses, as that was the energy taken to vaporize it to begin with).
If we have a container with a single type of gas, then molecules will move up and down randomly, but there is no energy changes, since a rising molecule will energetically balance out a falling one. But when there are two different gases with different densities ie different molecular weights, then if one type of gas accumulates above the other, then an energy difference is involved. How does this happen, without the upper gas cooling down and the lower one heating up, as this seems to break laws of thermodynamics (creating a temperature gradient where there was none, even if temporarily. Moreover, even after heat redistributes, it wouldn't explain how/why the gases were able to separate, since the upper gas has still stored potential energy that it took from the lower gas, where the amounts aren't necessarily equal).
With normal convection, you have two different regions of gas that are not identical. For example, hot water in a pot rising to the top. Even though the molecules are all identical, there are entire macroscopic regions where all the water near the pot bottom are hotter than the water at the top. It isn't possible for the two to mix fast enough and finely enough, so there are inhomogeneous regions. Hence there are density differences, and when the hot/lighter water rises (while remaining mostly as a single region amongst itself macroscopically), and it gets the energy it needs from the falling cold/heavier water that due to the higher density realeases more potential energy than the hot/lighter water that is rising would consume. The rest/difference goes to kinetic energy, thus affecting how fast the water convects. But with evaporation, the water is too microscopically finely distributed in the air, such that no macroscopic inhomogeneous regions arise, hence convection can't be used as an explanation. Equivalently, if in a pot the hot water molecules were evenly distributed with the cold ones to begin with, then it is no different than a case of thermal equilibrium, in which case it becomes clear that it is impossible for hotter water molecules to spontaneously start rising to the top while the colder ones fall to the bottom, hence creating a temperature gradient where none previously existed.


So why/how does it continue to rise, even though technically it is a gas here just like other elements of air, even though despite all the temperature differences around the earth, oxygen, nitrogen, co2, and trace gases usually don't separate under the influence of temperature differences. So why can water?

Water molecules don't rise through the atmosphere.   As you say, the water vapor will be at the same temperature as the parcel of air.   But a warm, moist parcel might rise compared to a nearby cool, dry parcel.

Why can water disperse non-homogeneously in air, then mix homogeniously, then separate non-homogeneously again in clouds, while other gases all mix evenly, despite density differences?

Because the saturation density of water changes significantly with temperature.   Rising parcels of air lower in temperature.   If this parcel contains more water than the saturation density at the cooler temperature, the water will condense out.   No other gas in our atmosphere will be affected by common temperatures in this way.

I appreciate the attempt to answer the question, but you described the inhomogeneous case, for which I provided the example with the heated pot. That case is understood. The question is about the steady-state case where there are no temperature differences.
But given some short-sighted "moderator" got confused by the multiple question marks/parts of the question, closed this despite them being innately related to the same issue/problem. I won't bother posting the answer I worked out for the homogeneous case.
